# Select all and delete in outliner search results

Tags: outliner

Here's my problem...

I have many objects which I've duplicated but didn't notice myself duplicating the camera while I was in side view:

[image]

Now this is ok, because I've spotted a search box. I can find/delete...

[image]

Except deleting (while mouse is in 3D view) only deletes the one white-selected camera. The `a` key does toggle a form of selection, but instead of being an actual selection it's more of a doesn't do anything at all selection. The outliner is pretty unresponsive to what I would think of as typical user interaction.

How do I actually-select lots of things in the outliner?

---

I have just noticed that without search results I can make a doesn't-do-anything selection, right click and choose "select" to create an actual-selection. Either `a` all or `b` box select works to make a doesn't-do-anything selection. I can't however create typical shift-select between first and last so I think I need a bigger monitor to display more outliner for my box select. This right click "select" method doesn't work on doesn't-do-anything selections after filtering the outliner with the search box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selecting in the outliner would mark its list items as selected but does not select the objects you want to remove. To select more than one object in the outliner you can <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>LMB</kbd> each object.

Instead you could select them by name in *Object Mode* *Menu:Select / Select pattern*, Type Camera.* (this omits the default camera) and press <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly what you asked, but might come in handy anyway:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.select = ( obj.name[:3] == "Cub" )
```

It's a python script you can paste into blender's Text Editor and then Run Script.  (although the Text Editor starts out without any text buffer and you have to click New to make it typable/pasteable).

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered that selecting things in the outliner using keys like <kbd>a</kbd> or the <kbd>b</kbd> box-select does not equate to selecting them in the 3-D view (in contrast to mouse clicking the outliner item).

Fortunately, if you right-click in the outliner you get a menu whose first entry is "Select" which can transfer the selection from the outliner to the 3D view.  One caveat is that the menu will **not** pop up if you happen to have the Scene "selected" (often happens if you use the <kbd>a</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks! In my version (2.75.1), sometimes the menu will only pop up when you right click a non-selected item. Eventually I got it to work, but it's quite buggy. Hopefully fixed in something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

Select one of the Cameras

Go to

Select > Grouped > Type

or simple

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>T</kbd>

Note: This will obviously delete all objects of that type. So unselected anything you don't want to delete.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I took the liberty to add formatting for keystrokes. You may want to look at what exactly I did, to learn how to do it yourself. https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/78717/revisions. You may also want to take the [tour] and/or browse through the [help].

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the outliner and with your mouse cursor go to that little empty space next to the object that you want to remove (in my case it where 400+ particles) hit the `B` to do a group select and scroll down hit `B` again than that way you can select all your desired objects you want to remove and right click and delete to delete the selected list at once...