# How can I select hundreds of items in the outliner that have similar names?

Tags: selection-tools, outliner

I made an asteroid belt from a particle system. Lets say there are 2500 individual asteroids. There are 9 unique models. All the objects are named AsteroidA_LP..., AsteroidB_LP..., etc. all the way to AsteroidI_LP. That makes about 277 asteroids of each type that I need to select so that I can combine them into one object for each different type. I hope to end up with 9 objects, each containing the same type of asteroid that is UV Mapped the same.

I don't know the best way to do this. Here is what I am doing which beats Shift LMB clicking each one.

I have expanded the Outliner is large as I can. I LMB click to select the first object. I press B and drag a box selection across as many of the same type that I can and then I scroll the outliner and repeat the process until I have all the AsteroidA_LP objects selected with a shade of light blue. Once I have all the objects selected in that manner with box select then I RMB click and choose to select the objects and then press Ctrl+J to join all the objects together.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15657/select-all-and-delete-in-outliner-search-results

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try *Select > Pattern*. This will allow you to select objects based on a pattern with a set of wildcards.

[image]

The available wildcards are `*`, `?`, and `[...]`

- Use `*` to match any number of characters
- Use `?` to match a single character
- Use `[abc]` (or `[ABC]`, but this only matters if *Case Sensitive* is enabled) to match any letter, and `[0123456789]` to match any number between 0 and 9. You can match specific numbers too, e.g. `[127]` will only match `1`, `2`, and `7`.

If you want to select all AsteroidA_LP... objects, then it sounds like you want something like `AsteroidA_LP.*`.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for, just not where I was looking for it. :)