# Joining duplicate objects automatically

Tags: objects

I'm trying to join several duplicates to the master object at once. Thank you. For example, I mean joining SOMETHING_1 and SOMETHING_1.001 together, and so on.

Comment: Select all the duplicate objects using SHIFT key one at a time, then lastly, do the same with the original Master object.  With the duplicates highlited red and the Master highlited orange you can use  CTL-J to join permanently, or CTL-P to do the same but non-destructively. (i.e. you can undo the parenting later with ALT-P)  If using CTL or ALT-P, choose the "Keep Transform" option to avoid animation issues.

Comment: Recommend  the select pattern operator.  Single select original, then select pattern `SOMETHING_1.*` case sensitive true, extend true. then join.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24301/how-can-i-select-hundreds-of-items-in-the-outliner-that-have-similar-names